# Macros in c & C++

Tags: c, macros

Is it possible to define or undefine macros during runtime.

Comment: MACROS are _expanded_ before compilation time, so they essentially "dissolve" into the code beyond recognition. On a side note, even though your question is in the "c" realm, I'll take a shot at my prophetic abilities and suggest using any one of C++'s polymorphism.

Answer (score 11):

No. Macros are a preprocessor mechanism, and are fully resolved even before the compiler executes.

Their purpose is to alter the source code that the compiler sees, so they don't even exist at runtime (let alone permit modification).